# EF Core-2-2 HasConversion Char(1) to bool

Tags: c#, type-conversion, entity-framework-core

I'm converting an old SQL Server DB design to EF Core 2.21. The DB design is not practical to change. One field is a Char(1) with 'X' for true. I've added a .HasConversion however it is not working. The values are not converted and after a change and trying to save I get "Object of type 'System.Boolean' cannot be converted to type 'System.String". I am referencing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions where it says conversions can be from a value of one type to a value of another type. What am I missing? Can this be done?

```
entity.Property(e => e.LockNote)
    .HasColumnName("LOCK_NOTE")
    .HasMaxLength(1)
    .IsUnicode(false)
    .HasConversion(v => v == "X" ? true : false, v => v == true ? "X" : "");
```

Comment: In the end, what's the **type** of the `LockNote` **property**? Looks like you are doing the conversion other way around (the opposite of what it should be - the property type should be `bool` and the conversion should be to/from `string`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [built-in BoolToStringConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#built-in-converters):

```
var converter = new BoolToStringConverter("", "X");

entity.Property(e => e.LockNote)
    .HasColumnName("LOCK_NOTE")
    .HasMaxLength(1)
    .IsUnicode(false)
    .HasConversion(converter);
```

Comment: So close - however there seems to be two problems. The first is easy enough in this  case: I had an error regarding null values and the Char(1) can be null in this case so I updated all nulls to a blank '' and added the default value. However even without any null values I get a System.ArgumentException: 'The string argument 'falseValue' cannot be empty.' exception when loading data so it seems the built in converter will not take a blank string as an argument. I could populate the blanks with another character but at this point that seems like the tail wagging the dog and not what I want.-Thx

Comment: I just tried adding a period to see what would happen (".", "X") and that generates a System.ArgumentException: 'Converter for model type 'bool' cannot be used for 'TrkNote.LockNote' because its type is 'string'.' exception - so it looks like I need a currently mythical StringToBooleanConverter ...

Comment: @azpc what is the type of `LockNote`? You can also try to set it to `bool` and define this property without `.HasMaxLength(1).IsUnicode(false)` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both Ivan an Yuri. You both lead me to the answer that was not at all intuitive for me. The LockNote field is a Char(1) field that had come over as a string property in the table class. I needed to change that in the table class to a bool property and then I used the following:

```
var boolCharConverter =
    new ValueConverter<bool, string>(v => v ? "X" : "", v => v == "X");

entity.Property(e => e.LockNote)
    .HasColumnName("LOCK_NOTE")
    .IsUnicode(false)
    .HasConversion(typeof(string))
    .HasConversion(boolCharConverter);
```

with further testing it turns out that I can also remove the following without issues and further simplify the solution.

```
    .IsUnicode(false)
    .HasConversion(typeof(string))
```